# RUBY - Hash and Array // Explanation of a method use

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have a `hash`, where each key has a value (an integer). What I want to do is to create a method, where I write as an argument an `array`, this `array` will have written inside the name of the different keys.

So once I give the `array` to the method, it will sum all the values from each element. But I am not sure how to go through my `array`, and put all the elements inside the `hash`, and then sum it, and get the total value.

**Here is my code:**

```
DISHES_CALORIES = {
  "Hamburger" => 250,
  "Cheese Burger" => 300,
  "Veggie Burger" => 540,
  "Vegan Burger" => 350,
  "Sweet Potatoes" => 230,
  "Salad" => 15,
  "Iced Tea" => 70,
  "Lemonade" => 90
}

def poor_calories_counter(burger, side, beverage)
  DISHES_CALORIES[burger] + DISHES_CALORIES[side] + DISHES_CALORIES[beverage]
end

def calories_counter(orders)
  # TODO: return number of calories for a less constrained order
  sum = 0
  orders.each { |element| sum = sum + DISHES_CALORIES[":#{element}"] }
end
```

Comment: can the hashes named as a constant(fully Upcase)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, but:

1. You don't need to do anything with your order to make it an index.
2. `orders.each` will just return `orders` when it's done.
3. You need to handle `DISHES_CALORIES[element]` returning `nil`.

You can pass a block to `#sum`.

```
def calories_counter(orders)
  orders.sum { |order| CALORIES_COUNTER[order] || 0 }
end
```

Comment: `CALORIES_COUNTER[order].to_i` is another way to deal with possible `nil`s

Comment: Perfect! Now I understand what you are saying!!

Comment: As a relative newcomer to Stack Overflow, I'd like to remind you that you can say "thank you" by upvoting and/or marking an answer you feel has answered your question as accepted.

Comment: You might find `orders.sum { |order| CALORIES_COUNTER.key?(order) ? CALORIES_COUNTER[order] : 0 }` reads better. Considering that hash key lookups are very fast I expect this would be acceptable in from a performance standpoint.

Comment: Yes, you should accept the answer that you find most helpful (provided there is a helpful answer), but there is no rush in doing so, as you do not wish to discourage other answers being offered.

Comment: Thanks to all, I would love to upvote the answer but I am not allowed to yet, because I am super new. But I press the green mark. Sorry again, about it, because I am a newbie in this world

"Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Answer (score 0):

You can also use default value of hash for calculating calories in all places without errors

```
DISHES_CALORIES.default = 0

def calories_counter(orders)
  orders.sum { |element| DISHES_CALORIES[element] }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could allow for multiple menu items like this:

```
choices = ["Hamburger","Salad","Lemonade"]

p DISHES_CALORIES.values_at(*choices).sum # => 355
```